# Is it possible to get Context Broker referencing several URLs'(i.e cygnus + POI)?

Tags: fiware-orion

I have already successfully installed CB, Cygnus and POI.  I want an entity to subscribe CB to reference Cygnus and POI (for persistence) in the same request.  My point is to avoid sending a subscription request to CB for every single process. I want something like that:

"reference1": "http://Cygnus_address:port1/notify",
"reference1": "http://POI_address:port2/notify",

Is that possible?. Sending n requests with the same content makes not sense.

Best

Answer (score 0):

`reference` field is single-valued, so you cannot do what you propose. However, doing an addition subscription with the new reference will have the the same effect.